# Copy Paste feature on R Studio experiencing bugs on M1 Mac mini running big sur

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, macos-big-sur

I tried to copy code from a blog on Data-flair training. https://data-flair.training/blogs/data-science-machine-learning-project-credit-card-fraud-detection/ The R Studio seems to have a bug where in the backspace and delete do not work as required. These two actions end up deleting more characters. However typing the code on the R Studio IDE seems to have no issues as far as backspace and delete functionality is concerned. Same action has no issues on macos bug sur running on intel based mac book pro.